# Hibernate empty SQL when migrating to Grails 2.5.1

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We are currently migrating a grails application from version 2.2.4 to version 2.5.1 and also JDK 6 to JDK 8.

All things didn't provide any problems except of one service for our master data. The service is used by all our CRUD controllers for masterdata. The controllers are scaffolded.

We are trying to migrate to Hibernate 4.3.10.

When doing CRUD operations on the mentioned service we get some assertions from Hibernate that says that one of the SQL statements is null. It seems that the problem occurs when the service is called for an user request more then once (e.g. for saving the entities and afterwards to calculate the redirect target, depending on the entity state).

We have played around with the @Transactional annotation and different propagation values on service and controller side, but this doesn't help.

Any ideas?

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Interceptor.onPrepareStatement() returned null or empty string.
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.onPrepareStatement(SessionImpl.java:550)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.<init>(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.<init>(StatementPreparerImpl.java:100)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.buildPreparedStatementPreparationTemplate(StatementPreparerImpl.java:100)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3238)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:552)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:73)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:147)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:87)
at de.test.data.OrgUnitController.show(OrgUnitController.groovy)
at de.test.data.OrgUnitController.show(OrgUnitController.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:375)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:252)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:205)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:126)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:347)
```